# ComplexHeatmap row_title_side not working

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple heatmap using ComplexHeatmap package, but row_title_side doesn't seem to be working or am I missing something?

a reproducible example is:

```
set.seed(1)
mat = matrix(rnorm(64), 8)
colnames(mat) = letters[1:8]
labels <- colnames(mat)

mat2 = cor(mat)
od = hclust(dist(mat2))$order
mat2 = mat2[od, od]
Heatmap(
  mat2,
  col = colorRamp2(c(-1, 0, 1), c("red", "white", "green")),
  cluster_rows = FALSE,
  cluster_columns = FALSE,
  heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "Cor"),
  rect_gp = gpar(type = "none"),

  row_title_side = 'left',

  cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, w, h, col) {
    if (i > j) {
      grid.rect(x, y, w, h, gp = gpar(fill = col))
      grid.text(sprintf("%.2f", mat2[i, j]), x, y)
    }
  }
)
```

With the code above I am getting this:[image: heatmap_image]

Comment: Do you need to add a `row_title`? Try adding `row_title = 'test title'` and see if it shows up on the left...or maybe you meant `row_names_side` instead to show c, h, a, b etc. on the left instead of right?

Comment: Thanks Ben, that did the trick. I must have been hallucinating. I meant row_names, and now the question looks ambiguous!